# Why do I obtain 2 differents results when filling range directly with array and doing it index by index?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have an array full of data that I want to write in a worksheet.

I obtain 2 differents results while doing this :

**1) Looping through indexes**

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(dataarray(), 1)

        For j = 0 To UBound(dataarray(), 2)

            With mWS_data
                .Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dataarray(i, j)
            End With

        Next j

    Next i
```

**2) Filling the range directly**

```
        With mWS_data
            'Row + 2 because datarray starts from 0, and 1st row is titles, Column + 1 because same reason but no titles
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(dataarray(), 1) + 2, UBound(dataarray(), 2) + 1)) = dataarray()
        End With
```

With the same data, in the first case I have all the data in the worksheet (correct result) and in the second case, I only have few datas (all the correct info of one column in the middle, and 1 cell with correct info on an other column).

My code was working perfectly fine last friday, there was absolutly no change in the code and today it is not working correctly.

I am use to code the second way because of much faster processing time.

**Is it possible that an excel setup interfer somehow ?**
**Or did I wrote somehting wrong ?**

**--- EDIT : ---**

Here is the full code with the simplifications you gave me

```
Sub Load()
    
    Dim dataArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c_attribute As New Cls_attribute
    
    ReDim dataArray(mJobs.Count - 1, attributes.Count - 1)
    
    'Turns off screen updating and auto calculation
        DisplayCalculation False
        
    'For each item into collection
        For i = 1 To mJobs.Count
            
            Index = i
            
            'Get data from its variable name
                For j = 1 To attributes.Count
                    
                    Set c_attribute = attributes.Item(j)
                    
                    On Error Resume Next
                    dataArray(i - 1, j - 1) = CallByName(Me, c_attribute.name, VbGet)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                    Set c_attribute = Nothing
                    
                Next j
            
        Next i
    
    With mWS_data
    
        'Remove previous data
            .Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete
        
        'Data to worksheet '[VERSION THAT WORKS]
            For i = 0 To UBound(dataArray, 1)
        
                For j = 0 To UBound(dataArray, 2)
        
                    .Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dataArray(i, j)
        
                Next j
        
            Next i
        
        'Data to worksheet '[VERSION THAT FAILS]
            '.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(dataArray, 1) + 1, UBound(dataArray, 2) + 1).Value = dataArray
    
    End With
    
    'Turns in screen updating and auto calculation
        DisplayCalculation True
    
End Sub
```

Though I can not show you the data because it is confidential and not GDPR compliant :

- When it works : 56 rows and 68 columns of datas complete
  [image: Normal result]
- When it fails : same range is filled, but only "AG" column and "AH44" cell contain datas.
  [image: Fail result]

Comment: Can't see a problem but second way can be written more simply as     `.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(dataArray), UBound(dataArray, 2)) = dataArray
`

Comment: If you are populating your arrray something like `dataarray = Sheet3.Range("A1:B12")` then the array starts at 1 and not 0. Make that adjustment and it will probably solve your problem.

Comment: CDP1802, thanks for the simplification, I will check on that. 

Charlie, I though about that, but that is not the issue since the array is "Redim" then populated index by index from different collections and dictionnary datas.

Comment: Okay, could you may be add a snap of result from both the cases and also show how  and with what `dataarray` is getting populated ?

Comment: How big is the array ?

Comment: I added information through editing original question.

Answer (score 0):

### Write a 2D Zero-Based Array to a Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteArrayToWorksheet()
    
    Dim DataArray As Variant: ReDim DataArray(0 To 4, 0 To 9) ' 5*10, 'A2:J6'
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For r = 0 To 4
        For c = 0 To 9
            DataArray(r, c) = (r + 1) * (c + 1)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Remember: 'UBound(DataArray, 1)', 'UBound(DataArray,2)', 'DataArray'.
    ' Correct: .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(DataArray, 1) + 2, UBound(DataArray, 2) + 1)).Value = DataArray
    ' Wrong:   .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(DataArray(), 1) + 2, UBound(DataArray(), 2) + 1)) = DataArray()
    
    With mWS_data
        ' Row + 2 because DataArray starts from 0, and 1st row is titles, Column + 1 because same reason but no titles
        
        ' Correct:
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(DataArray, 1) + 2, UBound(DataArray, 2) + 1)).Value = DataArray
        
        ' I prefer using 'Resize':
        '.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(DataArray, 1) + 1, UBound(DataArray, 2) + 1).Value = DataArray
    
    End With

End Sub
```